# cannot find name with typescript and deno

Tags: typescript, deno

Here is my code :

```
/**
 * map.ts
 */


// @deno-types="./libs/@types/geojson/index.d.ts"
// @deno-types="./libs/@types/mapbox-gl/index.d.ts"

mapboxgl.accessToken =  "toto";

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
  center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
  zoom: 9 // starting zoom
  });
```

But even if i have imported the definition of mapbox with

```
// @deno-types="./libs/@types/geojson/index.d.ts"
// @deno-types="./libs/@types/mapbox-gl/index.d.ts"
```

I have the error :

```
error: TS2304 [ERROR]: Cannot find name 'mapboxgl'.
mapboxgl.accessToken =  "toto";
~~~~~~~~
    at file:///home/bussiere/Workspace/testdeno2/map.ts:9:1

TS2304 [ERROR]: Cannot find name 'mapboxgl'.
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
              ~~~~~~~~
    at file:///home/bussiere/Workspace/testdeno2/map.ts:11:15

Found 2 errors.
```

How to import correctly the definition in a way that i could be able to use the name and the definitions.

here is the github :
https://github.com/bussiere/testdeno2

Edit :

here is the uncaught error :

```
error: Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: unreachable
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:336403)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:341096)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:339419)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:339781)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:336272)
    at <anonymous> (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:268321)
    at minify (wasm://wasm/00247702:1:253183)
    at minify (https://deno.land/x/minifier@v1.1.1/wasm.js:98:14)
    at minify (https://deno.land/x/minifier@v1.1.1/mod.ts:27:10)
    at https://deno.land/x/minifier@v1.1.1/cli.ts:53:3
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no reference of the library and I think you can install the package from skypack or pika to upgrade and downgrade easily instead of copying the lib to your repo.

Cache the 3rd party library by running `deno info`

```
deno info "https://cdn.skypack.dev/@types/mapbox-gl"
or 
deno info "https://cdn.pika.dev/mapbox-gl@^2.2.0"
```

Import the mapbox-gl with type definition

```
// @deno-types="./libs/@types/mapbox-gl/index.d.ts"
import mapboxgl from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/mapbox-gl";
// or import mapboxgl from "https://cdn.pika.dev/mapbox-gl@^2.2.0";

mapboxgl.accessToken = "toto";

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map", // container id
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11", // style URL
  center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
  zoom: 9, // starting zoom
});
```

Comment: i still have error: Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: unreachable thanks anyway

Comment: Can you share more info on the Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError:? i think the type problem should be fixed?

Comment: fund the uncaught have been shared